# java : how to get element from a list of array that has distinctive first characters

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of

```
 String [] animals = {"cat", "cheetah", "tiger","shark"}
```

I wanted to print only tiger and shark,
I have tried to code but it print duplicates of cat and cheetah too

below is the code I attempted

```
public static String[] getDistinctives(String list[]){

    String [] samefirst = new String [list.length];

    for(int i = 0; i< list.length ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< list.length ; j++){   
            if(list[i].charAt(0) == list[j].charAt(0)){
                System.out.println(list[i]);
            }
        }    
    }
    return samefirst;
}
```

it gives output off

```
cat
cat
tiger
shark
cheetah
cheetah
```

but I only want

```
tiger
shark
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!! thank you!!

Comment: Fist j should start at j=i+1 and after it check all the works if it did not find a another word with the same letter save the index in another array, then print the words with the save index

Comment: well it's printing them twice because you're saying "if they have the same first letter, print it". So when it's checking cat for example, it checks it against itself and thus the first letter is the same, so it prints it. Then it checks it against cheetah, and they have the same first letter, so it prints it. Hence it prints cat twice. Same thing for cheetah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String[] getDistinctives(String list[]){

    String [] samefirst = new String [list.length];


    for(int i = 0; i< list.length ; i++){
        int flag=0;
        for(int j = 0; j< list.length ; j++){   
            if( (list[i].charAt(0) == list[j].charAt(0)) && (i!=j) ){
                flag=1;
            }
        }

        if(flag==0) {
            System.out.println(list[i]);   
        }
    }
    return samefirst;
}
```

Try this. I  hope this is what you want.

Comment: but i dont understand , what does flag do?

Comment: If you start from j=i+1 there is no need of i!=j in the if, also is faster

Comment: flag notifies if another same first character is found. if you start with j=i+1 the loop will not check previous elements for equality

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing when it finds a duplicate (including itself), but you actually want to *skip* when a duplicate is encountered (excluding itself). This may not be the most efficient solution, but I think it's what you were aiming for:

```
outer:
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        if (i != j && list[i].charAt(0) == list[j].charAt(0)) {
            continue outer;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list[i]);
}
```